# Combining two aligned overlapping rasters in raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have two rasters with the same extent, projected coordinate system, cell size and they are aligned.

"raster1" has continuous values ranging from 0 to 6.09
"raster2" has continuous values from 0 to 91.25

What I need to do is creating a new raster in which, cells that have "value=0", based on "raster1", they will remain 0 but in any other case, cells will be assigned a value based on the sum of the values from "raster1" & "raster2".

The expression I use in Raster Calculator is :

```
Con(("raster1" == 0), 0, (Con(("raster1" > 0) & ("raster2"  >= 0)), ...?
```

Obviously, this is not complete.  What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Con("raster1" == 0,0, ("raster1" + "raster2"))
```

Comment: Amend )) to ), 0.0) to account for first condition.

Comment: Seems to work fine the way it is.

Comment: Oops, missed 0,0

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer If this worked for you (check mark).